# What is returned in a jQuery function?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to understand what's inside a jQuery select, so I wrote this to alphabetically sort the properties:

```
var X = $('p:first');
console.log(X);
$(X).each(function(index,Element) {
    var prop;
    var arr = [];
    for (prop in Element) {
        arr[arr.length] = prop;
    }
    arr = arr.sort();
    for (var i=0,ii=arr.length;i<ii;i++) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
});
```

Is this the way that you would sort the property names, or am I working too hard?

Comment: Looks fine to me. If you're really interested in what each of the properties does and is for, checkout the jQuery src. Its not too difficult and make jQuery make a lot more sense.

Comment: Looks about right. I'd use `arr.push(prop)` for readability, but I guess that's personal style. Also, be aware that you will get any inherited properties as well; if you don't want that, use `if (Element.hasOwnProperty(prop))`. Another thing that is an issue of style, but rather more important: don't use variables that start with a capital unless they are meant to be called as constructors. There is a big difference if a function is called with `new` and without it, and the only clue we normally have is this piece of convention (constructors start with capitals, regular functions don't).

Comment: Those elements you get are references to the actual DOM nodes, so their properties aren't very mysterious :-)

Comment: Fyi, there's no need to use `$(X)` instead of `X` which is already a jQuery object.

Comment: @Amadan, you're right.  When I added if (Element.hasOwnProperty(prop)), it removed every property except 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is getting all the properties defined for a [paragraph html element](http://krook.org/jsdom/HTMLParagraphElement.html) including inherited properties.

One other way to get and sort all those properties is to use the built-in [`keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method on [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object),

```
Object.keys($('p')[0]).sort()
```

or the equivalent in plain JavaScript,

```
Object.keys(document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0]).sort()
```